# How to change Android Minimum SDK in .Net Maui Project?

Tags: android, maui

I have a .Net Maui 7 project.

Whenever I try to build the solution, I'm getting the error:

```
Error   AMM0000 uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library ..\obj\Release\net7.0-android33.0\lp\146\jl\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might
 be using APIs not available in 19.
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.security" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Whenever that happens, I change

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
```

But right after, for the next build, the problem occurs again.

How can I change that once for all?

Here is the project configuration:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />`? You can delete that line, see what happens when you rebuild. Make sure you have the latest stable (not preview) `maui-android`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever that happens, I change ...

Sounds like you are trying to change it in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

- REMOVE that line completely.
- Let `YourProject.csproj` control it. Similar to:

```xml
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

---

One way to discover what works, is to create a new Maui project. Build and run. Examine `YourProject.csproj` and `Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml`.

IIRC, `uses-sdk` won't exist in this copy of `AndroidManifest.xml`.
It gets added in the "merged/generated" `AndroidManifest.xml` in a subfolder of `.obj` folder.

Comment: I tried the above by setting the platform location (Which gets merged to the obj location, correct?) with no luck BUT found that setting this min SDK setting via the VS manifest GUI was NOT changing the XML file. Had to raw edit the XML manifest file and the Uses SDK statement: