Visual Studio MAUI deploy to Android API 34
My question is probably a bit different than others.  I am trying to work on a new MAUI project with Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.9.6).  The MAUI is .net8, Android 14 (API 34). The device I am deploying to is a Honeywell scanner running Android 9 as detected environment.
On another live project I have for this device, its built under the older version and when I build the project, VS creates the .apk installer package, gets deployed and runs.  However, trying to build and deploy MAUI, I get device not supported. (Error ADB0040: Mono.AndroidTools.SdkNotSupportedException.  The device does not support the minimum SDK level specified in the manifest.)
So, I looked into Android Studio just as a test. Created a brand new app on that, using Android API 34, with simple Hello Android message default project, no changes and deployed to same Honeywell device and it worked. (Unlike VS Error ADB0040)
Obviously things are different between VS2022 and Android Studio.  How can I get this MAUI app to get installed as a package as the ultimate end-user devices for the client wont have any direct access to such a development environment to push the API for deployment purposes.
From Comments:
The specific device is a Honeywell CN80 handheld scanner.  Its a 64-bit unit, O/S and Android configuration handled by Honeywell installer.  But strange thing is Android Studio WILL deploy and work, but Visual Studio 2022 does not.

@Robert, updated details in post

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76789800/150978
